# MongoDB text index search

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, database-administration, mongo-shell

I had created a collection in mongo db as show below

```
db.articles.insert([
 { _id: 1, subject: "one", author: "abc", views: 50 },
 { _id: 2, subject: "lastone", author: "abc", views: 5 },
 { _id: 3, subject: "firstone", author: "abc", views: 90  },
 { _id: 4, subject: "everyone", author: "abc", views: 100 },
 { _id: 5, subject: "allone", author: "efg", views: 100 },
 { _id: 6, subject: "noone", author: "efg", views: 100 },
 { _id: 7, subject: "nothing", author: "abc", views: 100 }])
```

after that I given text indexing to the field subject and author.

```
db.articles.createIndex(
    {subject: "text",
    author: "text"})
```

Now I am trying to search a word with "one" in indexed field. When I execute query ...

```
db.articles.count({$text: {$search: "\"one\""}})
```

... the result is `1`.

The problem is that when I want combination of words "one", "abc" ...

```
db.articles.count({$text: {$search: "\"one\" \"abc\""}}
```

... it gives the result as `4`. Including the records that contains the subject name as "lastone", "firstone", "everyone", "one" as the result.

So my question is that why the first query dosn't fetch 4 records? And how can I write a query that can fetch 4 records with word "one"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command ...

```
db.articles.count({$text: {$search: "\"one\""}})
```

... will count the documents having the exact phrase `"one"`. There is only one such document, hence the result is `1`.

Querying with the vaule "one" should only return on document since there is only one document containing either "one" or some value for which "one" is a stem. From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#stemmed-words):

> For case insensitive and diacritic insensitive text searches, the `$text` operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a document field contains the word **blueberry**, a search on the term **blue** will not match. However, **blueberry** or **blueberries** will match.

Looking at the documents in your question ...

- `one` is not a stem of `everyone`
- `one` is not a stem of `lastone`
- `one` is not a stem of `allone`
- `one` is not a stem of `firstone`
- `one` is not a stem of `noone`

... so none of these documents will be matched for the value `one`.

You can, of course, query with multiple values. For example:

- The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms) suggest that this should be evaulated as `one or abc` and it correctly returns 5:

  ```
  db.articles.count({$text: {$search: "one abc"}})
  ```
- The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) suggest that this should be evaulated as `"abc" AND ("abc" or "one")` and it correctly returns 5:

  ```
  db.articles.count({$text: {$search: "\"abc\" one"}})
  ```
- The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) suggest that this should be evaulated as `"one" AND ("one" or "abc")` but it somehow returns 4:

  ```
  db.articles.count({$text: {$search: "\"one\" abc"}})
  ```

In the last example MongoDB includes the documents with subject in "one", "lastone", "firstone", "everyone" but excludes the document with subject "nothing". This suggest that it has somehow deemed "one" to be a stem of "lastone", "firstone" and "everyone" but when executing `count({$text: {$search: "one"}})` it returns `1` which clearly indicates that `one` is not seen as a stem of "lastone", "firstone" and "everyone".

I suspect this might be a bug and might be worth [raising with MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/SERVER/issues/SERVER-34204?filter=allopenissues).

FWIW, it's possible that what you actually want is a partial string search in which case [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#regex) might work. The following query ...

```
db.articles.count({ subject: { $regex: /one$/ }, author: { $regex: /abc$/ } })
```

... means something like `count where subject like '%one%' and author like '%abc%'` and for your documents that returns `4` i.e. the documents where `subject` is one of "one", "lastone", "firstone", "allone", "everyone", "noone" and `author` is "abc".

Comment: I don't get that. `db.articles.count({author: "abc"})` returns 5 not 3 documents. Why you said that there are three documents with "abc" ?

Comment: @glytching I also find result of db.articles.count({author: "abc"}) as 5 as mickl told

Comment: `5` is the correct count for 'documents containing abc'. I have updated the answer. This does not change the explanation for why you are not matching more than one document containing "one".

Comment: @glytching my doubt is that why it gives 4 when I search with the keyword "\"one\" \"abc\""?  if "one" only gives 1 result then the above case should return 1 rather than 4 right?

Comment: @Sameesh agreed, that is confusing. I have updated my answer in an attempt to address this.

Comment: @glytching when I execute db.articles.find({$text: {$search: "\"abc\"\"o\""}}) it gives  5 records, It perform partial searching effectivley. but db.articles.find({$text: {$search: "\"o\""}}) It wont give any records

Comment: This: `$search: "\"o\""` is an exact match on the term "o", there are no docs matching that. To be specific: "o" does not match "one". For more details read the docs on [phrases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) and on [stemmed words](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#stemmed-words).